# How to get all keys where its values are same and data type of values are always list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
mydict = {
    'name' : ['cat','dog'],
    'place' : ['earth','mars'],
    'name1' : ['cat','dog'],
    'name2' : ['cat','dog'],
    'place1' : ['earth','mars'],
    'colour' : ['blue','green'],
    'colour1' : ['orange']
}
```

expected_result

```
[['name','name1','name2'],['place','place1']]
```

Since `'colour'` and `'colour1'` are not same we will ignore them.

Comment: do you mean, you want to get the list of dict items where, keys are the same and values are the same too?

Comment: I want all keys where its values are same

Comment: You would have to write some code. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the fastest solution, but you can find the duplicate values first, then list the corresponding keys:

```
>>> values = list(mydict.values())
>>> duplicates = set(tuple(v) for v in values if values.count(v) > 1)
>>> [[k for k, v in mydict.items() if tuple(v) == d] for d in duplicates]
[['name', 'name1', 'name2'], ['place', 'place1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
rev = defaultdict(list)
for i in mydict:
    rev[tuple(mydict[i])].append(i)

answer = [i for i in rev.values() if len(i)>=2]
#[['name', 'name1', 'name2'], ['place', 'place1']]
```